# Picasso Image Loading https with self signed certificates

Tags: android, ssl, picasso

I was working on picasso to display images into my android activity. But my server was having self signed certificates for HTTPS that's why i was giving me the following error:

```
 com.squareup.picasso.NetworkRequestHandler$ResponseException: HTTP 504
```

I previously fixed this issue for retrofit now I'm posting solution in the answer: You need to use the following RetrofitClient class which code is as under and update your certificates in method trustedCertificatesInputStream:

I hope this will save someones day :)

Answer (score -1):

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.security.GeneralSecurityException;
import java.security.KeyStore;
import java.security.cert.Certificate;
import java.security.cert.CertificateFactory;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;

import javax.net.ssl.HostnameVerifier;
import javax.net.ssl.KeyManagerFactory;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSession;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManager;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManagerFactory;
import javax.net.ssl.X509TrustManager;

import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import okhttp3.Response;
import okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor;
import okio.Buffer;
import retrofit2.Retrofit;
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory;

public class RetrofitClient {


    public static Retrofit getApiClient(String baseUrl) {

        HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);


        X509TrustManager trustManager;
        SSLSocketFactory sslSocketFactory;
        try {
            trustManager = trustManagerForCertificates(trustedCertificatesInputStream());
            SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
            sslContext.init(null, new TrustManager[]{trustManager}, null);
            sslSocketFactory = sslContext.getSocketFactory();
        } catch (GeneralSecurityException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .addInterceptor(interceptor)
                .sslSocketFactory(sslSocketFactory, trustManager)
                .hostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
                        return true;
                    }
                })
                .build();





        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(baseUrl)
                .client(client)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();

        Log.e("RetrofitClient", baseUrl);

        return retrofit;

    }



    public static OkHttpClient okClient(){
        HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);


        X509TrustManager trustManager;
        SSLSocketFactory sslSocketFactory;
        try {
            trustManager = trustManagerForCertificates(trustedCertificatesInputStream());
            SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
            sslContext.init(null, new TrustManager[]{trustManager}, null);
            sslSocketFactory = sslContext.getSocketFactory();
        } catch (GeneralSecurityException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .addInterceptor(interceptor)
                .sslSocketFactory(sslSocketFactory, trustManager)
                .hostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
                        return true;
                    }
                })
                .build();
        return client;

    }


    private static X509TrustManager trustManagerForCertificates(InputStream in)
            throws GeneralSecurityException {
        CertificateFactory certificateFactory = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
        Collection<? extends Certificate> certificates = certificateFactory.generateCertificates(in);
        if (certificates.isEmpty()) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("expected non-empty set of trusted certificates");
        }

        // Put the certificates a key store.
        char[] password = "password".toCharArray(); // Any password will work.
        KeyStore keyStore = newEmptyKeyStore(password);
        int index = 0;
        for (Certificate certificate : certificates) {
            String certificateAlias = Integer.toString(index++);
            keyStore.setCertificateEntry(certificateAlias, certificate);
        }

        // Use it to build an X509 trust manager.
        KeyManagerFactory keyManagerFactory = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(
                KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
        keyManagerFactory.init(keyStore, password);
        TrustManagerFactory trustManagerFactory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(
                TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
        trustManagerFactory.init(keyStore);
        TrustManager[] trustManagers = trustManagerFactory.getTrustManagers();
        if (trustManagers.length != 1 || !(trustManagers[0] instanceof X509TrustManager)) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Unexpected default trust managers:"
                    + Arrays.toString(trustManagers));
        }
        return (X509TrustManager) trustManagers[0];
    }

    private static KeyStore newEmptyKeyStore(char[] password) throws GeneralSecurityException {
        try {
            KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
            InputStream in = null; // By convention, 'null' creates an empty key store.
            keyStore.load(in, password);
            return keyStore;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new AssertionError(e);
        }
    }


    private static InputStream trustedCertificatesInputStream() {
        // PEM files for root certificates of Comodo and Entrust. These two CAs are sufficient to view
        // https://publicobject.com (Comodo) and https://squareup.com (Entrust). But they aren't
        // sufficient to connect to most HTTPS sites including https://godaddy.com and https://visa.com.
        // Typically developers will need to get a PEM file from their organization's TLS administrator.
        String comodoRsaCertificationAuthority = "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\n" +
                "MIIGHDCCBASgAwIBAgIJAL9YjcpQAkTLMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBCwUAMIGiMQswCQYD\n" +
                "VQQGEwJQSzEPMA0GA1UECAwGUHVuamFiMQ8wDQYDVQQHDAZNdWx0YW4xGzAZBgNV\n" +


                "j2pjtSNqRIxmXE1ZtOj4f/RxUMoYUSg3AKvG0zRq1WgpKPgqkSi4i3AUI7bXoX7B\n" +
                "ayGxYS6Dofx+LfQFugB3HVmn+7lpY/wb1Dp3z/wmi0xT+8BZL/qvI4ISS4mAPJ9d\n" +
                "77JwSrQ40qnuWXkoJwC8ubWPP9bQWxolzW2rFn2yRyz9Po/tOYfpV/hhDNbuumxW\n" +
                "MHVM3Z1pwTUM1xz8RlFE9uJOGVgMX/iikqZ1EMZ6QwIvXZ7Lcpd0Ov09xeeyIx0x\n" +
                "Gj/t9/7PdrDTkTUG3qZ/UJNqcD2dKBY5E7bZn5QhLSJBTva9vCC/N2i4+i77K/Cy\n" +

                "X/uaAUlYfUhBD4uet2C88syqtkW0+Vb0MuTO4sO1YSE=\n" +
                "-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n";

        return new Buffer()
                .writeUtf8(comodoRsaCertificationAuthority)
                .inputStream();
    }
}
```

and then use it to load your https images:

```
// let's change the standard behavior before we create the Picasso instance
// for example, let's switch out the standard downloader for the OkHttpClient
           picassoBuilder.downloader(new OkHttp3Downloader(RetrofitClient.okClient()));

// Picasso.Builder creates the Picasso object to do the actual requests
           Picasso picasso = picassoBuilder.build();



           Picasso.setSingletonInstance(picasso); //apply to default singleton instance
           picasso.get().load("https://xxxxxxxxxx.xxx/uploads/16_registration_1575959841.jpeg").noPlaceholder().fit().centerCrop()
                   .into(imageView, new com.squareup.picasso.Callback() {
                       @Override
                       public void onSuccess() {
                           Log.e("image Loade","image succssfully loaded");
                       }

                       @Override
                       public void onError(Exception e) {
                           Log.e("image Loade",e.toString());
                       }
                   });
       }
```

Comment: I'm aware of it. But there is no any other solution to use self signed certificate. @SteffenUllrich if you have anything in your mind please share

Comment: @SteffenUllrich what if we validate our own domain in the  public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {  if (hostname.equals("xxxx.cxx")) return true;else return false;   }

Comment: If you really need to use a self-signed certificate then you need to check that the certificate you got is exactly the same as expected. Just checking the subject will not help since an attacker can create a certificate with the same subject. I've marked the question as duplicate and the answer to the other questions actually explains on how to do this correctly.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I am trying to impliment your provided answer but  .sslSocketFactory(sslContext.getSocketFactory()) is deprecated. it needs trust manager object. Can you please guide how can i do?  or any other sample?